# How to link back to a specific Cognito-form entry? URL format for appending each entry's unique ID

Tags: cognito-forms

We can link to all the form's entries using the following:

```
https://www.cognitoforms.com/forms/[form name]/entries
```

How would we link to a specific entry?

Each entry generates a Basecamp Project via Zapier. 
How would we send Basecamp a link back to the data in Cognito?
Also, is is possible to make the link clickable when it appears in Basecamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to a specific entry by adding the entry number to the end:

```
https://www.cognitoforms.com/forms/[form name]/entries/[entry number]
```

This link will still require you to log into [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) to view/edit the entry, but will take you to the specified entry.  We are working on administrative share links, which would allow people with the link to view/edit individual entries without having to log into Cognito Forms.

Not sure about the Basecamp question.